# How to find runway direction classification, code number and code letter?

Tags: runways, icao, control-surfaces

I am creating a solution that generated the limitation surfaces for runways according to ICAO Annex 14. One of the parameters that I need is the runway directions classification, code number and code letter. But so far I only found one country that has this information in their AIPs.

Are there anyone who know this stuff enough, that would be able to provide some guidelines to how I could guess these information based on thresholds and declared distances etc?

Comment: Looking at three random AIP's (Denmark, Sweden, Norway), the aerodrome reference code is mentioned in all three (in the AD 2 text section). Which country are you having issues with exactly?

Comment: I've never heard the term "runway direction classification" before, and it is not mentioned in Annex 14 either. Are you sure you have the right name for it?

Comment: Didnt look in Sweden and norway documents yet, but was looking in UK AIPs. If you look in section 12 in the danish AIPs you will find Code letter, Code Number and Classification for each runway. Its PA_Cat 1 to 3 ect, NINST and NONP

Comment: "Runway direction" is from EuroControl AIXM format where a Runway is typical composed of two RunwayDirections.

Comment: Table 4-1. Dimensions and slopes of obstacle limitation surfaces — Approach runways

Comment: Cool. I was under the impression that runways also had a code used for these limitation surfaces.  I checked AIXM classes for the airport, though did not find this attribute there: https://ext.eurocontrol.int/aixmwiki_public/bin/view/AIXM/Class_AirportHeliport

Comment: Also, a danish airport has two different codes (EKYT) for their runways, ergo the code is not for the airport itself as it is different for those two runways. So I am confused by your argument

Comment: Each runway also has a code, otherwise you cant design the limitation surfaces for each runway. Lets say an airport has two runways, ofcause if one of them is large enough for a large airplane to land, then ofcause the airport reference code will also indicate this. But that dont mean that the large airplane can land at the other very small grass runway - and this also means that airports dont need to cut down trees for the grass runway just because large airplanes lands at the first runway. So for designing limitation surfaces, each runway has its own code.